# symfony2 unique validator cannot update a row

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, yaml

I created an Entity with an unique variable. I set both  the ORM to unique and in the validator as well. This allows me to create new rows, that has unique names, but doesnt allow me to update my existing rows, even if i just specify to update it.

validation.yml:

```
# src/Battlemamono/DatabaseBundle/Resources/config/validation.yml

Battlemamono\DatabaseBundle\Entity\Mamono:
    constraints:
        - Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity: 
            fields: name
            message: A mamono with this name already exists.
    properties:
        id:
            - Type: 
                type: integer

        name:
            - NotBlank: ~
            - MaxLength: 30
            - Type: 
                type: string

        family1:
            - NotBlank: ~
            - MaxLength: 30
            - Type: 
                type: string
            - Choice : { callback: getFamily }

        family2:
            - MaxLength: 30
            - Type: 
                type: string
            - Choice : { callback: getFamily }

        element1:
            - NotBlank: ~
            - MaxLength: 30
            - Type: 
                type: string
            - Choice : { callback: getElements }

        element2:
            - MaxLength: 30
            - Type: 
                type: string
            - Choice : { callback: getElements }

        disposition:
            - NotBlank: ~
            - MaxLength: 100
            - Type: 
                type: string
        diet:
           - NotBlank: ~
           - MaxLength: 100
           - Type: 
                type: string

        previousForm:
           - MaxLength: 30
           - Type: 
                type: string

        nextForm:
           - MaxLength: 30
           - Type: 
                type: string

        evolution:
           - MaxLength: 30
           - Type: 
                type: string

        evolutionLove:
          - Type: 
                type: bool

        tags:
          - Type: 
                type: string
          - MaxLength: 100

        description:
         - Type: 
                type: string
         - NotBlank: ~
```

action that does this:

```
public function editProccessAction($id, Request $request)
    {
        $form = $this->createForm(new MamonoType());
        if ($request->isMethod('POST'))
        {
            $form->bind($request);

            if ($form->isValid())
            {
                $FormData = $form->getData();
                $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
                $mamono = $em->getRepository('BattlemamonoDatabaseBundle:Mamono')->find($id);

                    if (!$mamono) {
                        $this->get('session')->getFlashBag()->add('notice', 'There is no such mamono in the database. Create it instead!');
                        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('battlemamono_database_create'));
                    }
                $mamono->setName($FormData->getName());
                $mamono->setFamily1($FormData->getFamily1());
                $mamono->setFamily2($FormData->getFamily2());
                $mamono->setElement1($FormData->getElement1());
                $mamono->setElement2($FormData->getElement2());
                $mamono->setDisposition($FormData->getDisposition());
                $mamono->setDiet($FormData->getDiet());
                $mamono->setPreviousForm($FormData->getPreviousForm());
                $mamono->setNextForm($FormData->getNextForm());
                $mamono->setEvolution($FormData->getEvolution());
                $mamono->setEvolutionLove($FormData->getEvolutionLove());
                $mamono->setTags($FormData->getTags());
                $mamono->setDescription($FormData->getDescription());
                $mamono->setUpdatedBy();
                $em->flush();

                $this->get('session')->getFlashBag()->add('notice', 'the Mamono was updated.');
                return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('battlemamono_database_homepage'));
            }
            else
            {
                return new Response($form->getErrorsAsString());
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: This where validation groups come in.  You need one group for creating and one group for editing.  The edit group will not have the unique constraint.

Answer (score 0):

You're not actually saving your entity:

```
//...
$mamono->save();
$em->flush();
```

Comment: Still got the same error even with that. Also that function wasnt writen in 'the Book' ...

Comment: name: ERROR: A mamono with this name already exists. family1: No errors family2: No errors element1: No errors element2: No errors disposition: No errors diet: No errors previousForm: No errors nextForm: No errors evolution: No errors evolutionLove: No errors tags: No errors description: No errors

Comment: OK the reason this is happening is that you are using the `UniqueEntity` constraint which is looking for a value in the `name` column.  The first time you save a particular Mamono, the name is not there and it saves successfully.  But the second time, the name is already there because it has been saved before.  I bet if you modify the `name` field in your entity object, before you save back, it will save without an error.  I don't know the solution unfortunately because I don't know this validator, but hopefully this puts you on the right track.

Comment: sadly i noticed that as well, and i didnt find any solution thats why i asked this....for now i just take it out.